# php / mysql: convenient way for replacing database?

Tags: phpmyadmin

i'm looking for a quicker way for replacing databases from my local to my live system.
currently i'm exporting in phpmyadmin, deleteing at my live server, importing - which is pretty time consuming. any better suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've been a web developer for a very long time (~15 years) and have been using the xxMP stack with phpMyAdmin for a very long time as well. If you are looking for a quicker way to do this *in phpMyAdmin* then you are out of luck, as it is the only way to migrate a database to production using phpMyAdmin (export then import).

That being said, remember that phpMyAdmin is just a GUI for MySQL using PHP. It will reflect any changes made to the underlying database. Therefore, you can do something relatively clever with replication: Set up your staging server (local database) as a Master, and set up the production system (remote database) as a Slave. Then disable replication on the Slave. This will prevent the Slave from replicating changes on the Master. After you've made all the changes you need to on your local/Master database, simply re-enable replication on the Slave. This will then migrate the changes over to your production server.